# Retrieve filepath for selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upload a file with the sendkeys function on the inputid.

I am currently using the path C:\Users\myusername\Documents\seleniumsolution\Utils\Dir\Dir1\Dir2\Dir3\UploadFolder\example.jpg

I see the file in my solution. But I dont want to give to complete path but only the filename and that selenium finds the path itself. Otherwise I will be the only one that can use this testcase.

I tried with:

```
var file = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), url);
```

And tried with:

```
string documents = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath),"UploadFolder");
```

Both of them dont give me the required result.

Hope that you guys can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to travel on the folders tree to get to the file

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

will get you in the `bin\debug` folder. From there you can use `parent` to move up to the file location. For example (might need some tweaking)

```
string solutionParentDirectory = Directory.GetParent(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName;
string file = Path.Combine(solutionParentDirectory, @"UploadFolder\example.jpg");
```

You can also try

```
string file = Path.GetFullPath("example.jpg");
```

Comment: It works, but isnt there a way to go direct the the selenium root directory?

Comment: @xxx2017 Added another option.

Comment: When I use string file = Path.GetFullPath("example.jpg");

I get filex = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\example.jpg"

Which is not correct.

Comment: @xxx2017 It works for me... I don't know any other way, sorry.